# $\sigma$-algebra and types of sample space

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

There are three types of sample spaces $\Omega$: 
1. finite 
2. countable (a.k.a. countably infinite) 
3. uncountable (a.k.a. uncountably infinite)

Given a $\Omega$ of any of these types, a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ will consist of measurable events only (i.e. events we can assign probabilities to).

In the case of the **uncountable $\Omega$** not all events will be measurable but the $\sigma$-algebra tells us which events we can assign probabilities to, so all is fine and dandy (since the $\sigma$-algebra include all events of practical interest).

Now, I am curious about the cases when $\Omega$ is either **finite** or **countable**. A $\sigma$-algebra is defined to be "closed under countable unions" (which also imply "closed under finite unions").

**My question is this**: In the case of a **finite $\Omega$**, or, **countable $\Omega$**, will the $\sigma$-algebra (given we choose the largest possible $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$) always include all possible events? In that case, the notion of a $\sigma$-algebra could almost be ignored since we could always just choose the *power set* as our *set of events*, right? But, to be closed under countable unions doesn't necessarily imply that the $\sigma$-algebra includes all possible events only because the $\Omega$ is countable (or finite), or does it? In such case please give intuition to why it implies all possible events are included in the $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Also in the case of uncountable $\Omega$ you can choose for the powerset. The restriction starts playing a part if you want to define a measure that has specific properties. At that stage we engage limits and the $\sigma$-algebra really comes in. In the case of countable $\Omega$ that sort of problems do not arise: choosing for the powerset does not restrict the measures that can be defined on the space. In short: $\sigma$-algebras are there to broaden our choice in *measures*.

Comment: @drhab Is it always guaranteed that all subsets of the power set of a $\Omega$ (be it a finite $\Omega$, countable $\Omega$, or, uncountable $\Omega$) can be given  a probability (i.e. the power set is always a $\sigma$-algebra)?

Comment: You can always find a probability measure that gives a value to every subset of $\Omega\neq\varnothing$. For instance let $\omega_0\in\Omega$ and let $P:\wp(\Omega)\to\mathbb R$ be prescribed by $A\mapsto1$ if $\omega_0\in A$ and $A\mapsto0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to both questions is negative:

1. The largest possible $\sigma$-algebra on any set (countable or not) is always the power set. Thus, if you want the largest possible $\sigma$-algebra, you are not left with a lot of coice.
2. Again, on any set there is a smallest $\sigma$-algebra, which is $\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$. This means that there is a $\sigma$-algebra (even on a finite) set, which isn't the power set.

Comment: But, will the power set of a countable $\Omega$ always include all possible events, or do their sometimes exist events in a countable $\Omega$ that are not included in the power set of $\Omega$?

Comment: By definition the power set contains complete informations

Comment: @cupernius I don't know what "complete informations" mean, but it sounds as if the answer to my question is yes.

Comment: Yes, the power set contains all possible events because, by definition, an event is a subset of $\Omega$, i.e. in the power set. With complete information I mean, that every subset of $\Omega$ is measurable